# When reload page , page not load after remove # from url in Angular 6.

Tags: angular, hash, routes, reload

In my angular 6 app, I got `#` in url.

Before

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(Approutes, { useHash: true }),
```

I have update as this.(Remove second parameter)

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(Approutes),
```

Then I have update `provider` also.

```
 {
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: PathLocationStrategy
 },
```

First time it works fine, But when I reload page, it doesn't work.

Comment: use `HashLocationStrategy` instead of `PathLocationStrategy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I have used same thing

```
RouterModule.forRoot(Approutes, { useHash: true }),
```

Also same thing as in any question. It solves my issue. I don't know how but it solves. When I got proper reason the how it solves I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the PathLocationStrategy instead of the HashLocationStrategy you have to configure your Webserver that it routes the requests to the indexpage of your Angular-Application. Otherwise the browser can't find the path (because the path does not exists in Filesystem of the webserver...)

Answer (score 0):

PathLocationStrategy requires a configuration on the server side to all the paths configured in @RouteConfig to be redirected to the main HTML page of your Angular application.

If you want achieve PathLocationStrategy  approach you can do it by

[**Angular Universal: server-side rendering**](https://angular.io/guide/universal)